Diode Does not Passing Voltage while Simulating Full Wave Rectifier in Advanced Design System (ADS)



I am new on ADS so i'm still trying to learn but now having some problems with simulating the full wave rectifier circuit on the first image. The diode does not pass the voltage through. I have tried more simpler one (half wave rectifier) like in the below image but it gave mV value outputs and does not give half wave instead of sine wave.


I tried to obtain a full rectified wave like this:


Where am i doing wrong?

If you can't get the half wave rectifier to work why have you compounded the question with a full wave rectifier that also doesn't work. My advice to you is postpone anything that involves full wave rectification and focus on the half wave rectifier. I'd also rewrite the question following that advice. In other words stick to the crux of the problem.

An AC analysis in ADS (or in the traditional SPICE simulators whose functionality it is replicating in the AC analysis) is a linearized simulation. It is assumed that all components behave linearly in this simulation.
So even though you specified a voltage source amplitude of 12 V, and in the real world this would be enough to forward bias the diodes for parts of the AC cycle in the real world, the AC analysis does not account for this.
The AC analysis assumes that the diode will behave like a parallel RC combination determined by the small-signal behavior at the operating point, regardless of how high a signal amplitude you apply.
If you want to see the nonlinear behavior of the diode in ADS (or SPICE) you can do a transient (TRAN) simulation instead of AC. In ADS you also have the possibility to do a harmonic balance simulation that will show you the harmonic responses produced by the high-amplitude signal through the diode...but there is a learning curve to interpreting the results (and 12 V may also be too strong a signal to get realistic results from the HB simulation).
Note: the last time I used it (a few years ago) ADS was also quite fussy about the source types matching the simulation --- you likely have to change your source to a transient source in order for it to produce a signal in the TRANsient simulation.
